# Windows 2008R2 RDP only works for Standard User but not for an Admin User

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, rdp, administrative-privileges

I have an issue which I cannot figure out. We have a Windows server 2008 set up. The user is setup to allow remote desktop and is a part of the Remote Desktop Users. When user is also part of the Administrator group and NLA is enabled then user cannot connect.

I can only get user to connect one of the 2 ways:

1. Either having the user setup as a standard user which causes problems with tasks which are already set up to run.
2. Switch off Network Level Authentication, which allows the user to connect even as Administrator.

Is there something I am missing? This used to work normally up until recently. It is possible it is some Windows Update which messed something up. I am not sure what that maybe.

Thank You!

Comment: Is the Windows right 'Deny access to this computer from the network' configured?

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that. It is not configured

Comment: Local account or domain account?

Comment: Local. No domain set up

Comment: There was a known issue with the January cumulative update that might be causing your problem, it was fixed by KB4487345, do you have that installed?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks! That fixed the problem. Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: @user218076, I've posted an answer.  You can accept it if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a known issue in the [January 2019 cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4480970/windows-7-update-kb4480970):

> Local users who are part of the local “Administrators“ group may not be able to remotely access shares on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 machines after installing the January 8th, 2019 security updates. This does not affect domain accounts in the local "Administrators" group.

The resolution is to install [KB4487345](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2).